# React application consuming too much Firebase download data

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I created a simple application that fetches the data from the firebase real-time database:

```
get(child(dbRef, `article`).then((snapshot) => {
            if (snapshot.exists()) {
                //processing 
            } else {
                console.log("No data available");
            }
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.error(error);
        });
```

I have around 100 articles in the database, which I am displaying on the frontend using react application.

As soon as I start my application and try using this page it downloads around 100 kb of data but Firebase shows that approx 300 MB is downloaded.

I am a bit confused about what I am doing wrong.

Below is the chart showing downloads in 1 hour, where I was fetching the list of articles and shows on the screen ( I tested it for 40 minutes):
[image: Firebse chart]

Every time I make a request chart shows 300-400 MB downloaded.

Please let me know if any other details are required to understand this issue.

Comment: Do you happen to host the application at firebase, too? Becaus than the extra data could be from the web app itself. 300MB seems a bit big for that, but it could be an explanation…

Comment: i was running the app on localhost only

Comment: It's not really clear to me how you are measuring the initial expected 100kb and what you are doing in your application that causes this behavior over time.  I think it would help if you edit the question to explain more fully how someone would reproduce this behavior and observe the same results that you're seeing.  It's very possible that your expectations are off, or that you have something wrong in your code that causes queries to execute more often than you think.

Comment: I checked in the developer's tool how much data has been downloaded for the request to get complete, it's approx 100kb.

Comment: @DougStevenson - will it help if I share the firebase app name and the data structure from the database and the way I am fetching it.

Comment: No, Stack Overflow volunteers don't have any visibility into the inner workings of your project.  We are working purely on our ability to reproduce a problem based on the data given in the question.  What you have right now isn't enough to construct a mental model of what might be going on, let alone reproduce the behavior.

Comment: let me try to create a simple demo of it.